# Can I enforce rgbdslam to save ply in binary?

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Saving ASCII ply is painfully slow, can I save it in binary mode?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65290/can-i-enforce-rgbdslam-to-save-ply-in-binary-?/) by [Benzwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4977/benzwr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. But you can find find the code for ply writing in [src/graph_mgr_io.cpp](http://alufr-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/src/graph_mgr_io.cpp) in the method

> void
> GraphManager::pointCloud2MeshFile(QString
> filename, pointcloud_type full_cloud)

If you know how to implement saving binary ply files, you can do it there. If you do so, I'd be interested in a patch.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0